# Replace bunch of numbers by letter

Tags: replacement, rule

I want to do following:

```
ArcTan[1/Sqrt[-1 + (4 Sqrt[2] x^2)/(5 xc^2)]] /.4 Sqrt[2]/5->a^2
```

I expect to have

```
ArcTan[1/Sqrt[-1 + x^2/(a^2 xc^2)]]
```

Mathematica cannot recognize 4 Sqrt[2]/5 in expression.

Comment: Please provide a short but complete example, not just a fragment.  Also explain what output you're expecting and what you actually got.

Comment: `/.4` is ambiguous, add a space to get `/. 4`

Comment: I was going to say what @Manuel --Moe-- G noted. I'll add that I for one believe this was a deplorable lexing/parsing decision, made by the wrong person, and retained ever since I have no idea why. The rule everywhere else is that a lexeme is as long as it can be. I will add that this bites me particularly hard because I often need to replace zeros (why that happens I don't know, but it does happen frequently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sqrt[5/3] + 1 /. Sqrt[5/3] -> a
(* 1 + a *)

Tanh[Sqrt[5/3] x] /. Sqrt[5/3] ->  a
(* Tanh[a x] *)
```

Try starting a new Mathematica session

Comment: sorry, I tried to keep it as simple as possible, but it does not cover my problem (see edit)

Comment: @belarus28 Copy this as is and execute `ArcTan[1/Sqrt[-1 + (4 Sqrt[2] x^2)/(5 xc^2)]] /. 4 Sqrt[2]/5 -> a^2`

Comment: wow! it was not working, and now in the new session it works... magic. thanks.